# icloud username an password forgot for iphone 6

Tags: icloud

How do I recover my user name an password for I cloud  for I phone 6? I know my apple Id an password.

Comment: It's the same. You can log in with Apple id or iCloud mail.

Comment: Ok, someone stole my I phone 6, and they had my apple Id an password changed. I figured out how to change them back an tried to use the find my I phone app. an it said put in your I cloud username an password. So I use my apple Id an password?

Comment: Yes you can put your Apple ID and password.